# Count number of days per month between two dates - SQL

Tags: sql

I'm very new to SQL so apologies if I am using the wrong terminology and if the code I have written is horrendous.

I'm trying to create a query to output the number of days per month per year. The test table I have created is `datetest`:

```
startdate    enddate
2105-12-16   2016-02-15
2017-01-01   2017-01-02
```

and using the query pasted below I get the following results:

```
Year  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
2015  31   15   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    16
2017  4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

The issue I'm having is when the date range goes over two years the result falls in the start date year not the actual year.

If anyone can help I would really appreciate it
Thanks

---

The Query

```
SELECT
year(startdate) AS Year,

SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-01-31') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-01-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0))+SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-01-31') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-01-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0)) AS "Jan",

SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-02-28') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-02-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0))+SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-02-28') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-02-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0)) AS "Feb",

SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-03-31') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-03-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0))+SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-03-31') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-03-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0)) AS "Mar",

SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-04-30') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-04-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0))+SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-04-30') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-04-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0)) AS "Apr",

SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-05-31') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-05-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0))+SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-05-31') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-05-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0)) AS "May",

SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-06-30') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-06-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0))+SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-06-30') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-06-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0)) AS "Jun",

SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-07-31') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-07-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0))+SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-07-31') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-07-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0)) AS "Jul",

SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-08-31') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-08-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0))+SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-08-31') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-08-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0)) AS "Aug",

SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-09-30') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-09-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0))+SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-09-30') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-09-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0)) AS "Sep",

SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-10-31') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-10-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0))+SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-10-31') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-10-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0)) AS "Oct",

SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-11-30') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-11-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0))+SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-11-30') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-11-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0)) AS "Nov",

SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-12-31') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(startdate), '-12-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0))+SUM(GREATEST(datediff(least(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-12-31') AS DATETIME),enddate),greatest(CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(enddate), '-12-01') AS DATETIME),startdate))+1,0)) AS "Dec"

from datetest

GROUP BY year(startdate)
```

Comment: which rdbms? sql-server, mysql, oracel, ...?

Comment: `2105-12-16`?  Should that be a year *before* 2016?

Comment: im sure ur making something horrible :d

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Matt but I don't think this will help me as the database is MySQL. What I'm building is using Wordpress so the data is collected via Gravity Forms and then I am using a plugin called wpDataTables to show the data in charts. Most of the data is super simple to query as it happens at an instant but the data I am having trouble with happens over a period of time.

Answer (score 1):

so I know you are not using sql-server looking at your syntax so this concept might work for you or not depending on the rdbms you have.  But the concept is to create a tally table of the highest number of difference between the 2 dates, then use that to join to the original table and flatten the date range to individual rows then simply pivot that information back.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (startdate DATETIME, enddate DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Table (startdate, enddate) VALUES ('2015-12-16','2016-02-15'),('2017-01-01','2017-01-02')

;WITH cteTally as (
    SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(day,startdate,enddate)) - 1 as Tally
    FROM
       @Table

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Tally - 1
    FROM
       cteTally
    WHERE
       Tally - 1 >= 0
)

, cteDates AS (
    SELECT
       DATEADD(day,c.Tally,t.startdate) as date
       ,YEAR(DATEADD(day,c.Tally,t.startdate)) as [Year]
       ,LEFT(DATENAME(month,DATEADD(day,c.Tally,t.startdate)),3) as [Month]
    FROM
       @Table t
       INNER JOIN cteTally c
       ON DATEDIFF(day,t.startdate,t.enddate) - 1 >= c.Tally
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cteDates
    PIVOT (
       COUNT([date])
       for [Month] IN ([Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],[Jul],[Aug],[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec])
    ) p
```

oracle, postgressql, and sql-server support this type of structure where as mysql will not.